# How to make each number, 1-1000, to show what it is e.g. odd/even, more than 500

Tags: c#, loops

OK. I have been trying this code for a long time now. I want to write a program which prints out the numbers 1-1000. For each number, I want it to show if it is odd/even, whether or not it is smaller than 250, bigger than or equal to 250 and less than 500, bigger than or equal to 500 and less than 750 or bigger than or equal to 750. This is my code, but it doesn't work, and I have searched over the IE and found nothing to help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++) ;

        if ((i % 2) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " is even ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " is odd ");
        }
        if (i < 250)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" is less than 250");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        if (i >= 250)
        {
            if (i < 500)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" is greater than or equal to 250 and less than 500 ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            if (i >= 500)
            {
                if (i < 750)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" is greater than or equal to 500 and less than 750 ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                if (i >= 750)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" is greater than or equal to 750  ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
```

I think it is the "i" s as there are errors saying that it doesn't exist in the current context. How do make it so it doesn't say that at makes the code better? Have I got the rest correct. Please help.

Comment: i made it all smell nice again - added homework tag :)

Comment: Strange once you leave university how homework has a distinct odor to it.  Something that's definitely not pleasant.

Answer (score 11):

Your for loop never executes anything, except "empty instructions". Remove the `;` at the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++) ;
```

Also surround the following instructions with curly braces:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
{
    // rest of instructions
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Trying removing the `;` behind it, and enclosing the rest of your code in `{`…`}`.

You can also reduce the size of your code significantly by merging your `if`…`else` statements together, and removing redundant checks.

Finally, don’t forget to place your `Console.ReadLine` outside the loop (unless you want to pause the program after each number).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
{
    if ((i % 2) == 0)
        Console.Write(i + " is even ");
    else
        Console.Write(i + " is odd ");

    if (i < 250)
        Console.WriteLine("and is less than 250");
    else if (i < 500)
        Console.WriteLine("and is greater than or equal to 250 and less than 500 ");
    else if (i < 750)
        Console.WriteLine("and is greater than or equal to 500 and less than 750 ");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("and is greater than or equal to 750 ");     
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: i've edited it. it works. however, i wanted each statement, like is greater than whatever, to be on the same line, like a sentence, so it would go like 501 is odd and is greater than or equal to 500. do you know what i mean?

Comment: i've edited it. it works. however, i wanted each statement, like is greater than whatever, to be on the same line, like a sentence, so it would go like 501 is odd and is greater than or equal to 500. do you know what i mean?

it comes to say,
501 is odd
    is greater than or equal to 500

why does this happen?

Comment: For that, you need to use `Write` for your first output (in order not to start a new line), and add the word `"and"'. Check the updated code above.

Answer (score 1):

As Tudor pointed, you should remove the `;` after the for statement.

You've also forgotten to wrap everything that should be inside the loop in curly braces, `{` and `}`.